# mysql reporting syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prestamos LEFT JOIN libros  on  prestamos.codlibros = libros.cod_libros where id_usuariospr ={$_SESSION['idusuarios']}");
$row = mysql_num_rows($sql);

//$datos = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
while($datos = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

    $tit = $datos['titulo'];
    $aut = $datos['autor'];
    $edit = $datos['editorial'];
    $isbn = $datos['isbn'];
    $color = $datos['color'];                
    $fechaP = $datos['fecha_prest'];
    $fecha = $datos['fecha_entrega'];
    $libro = $datos['codlibros'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO historial(titulo_his, autor_his, editorial_his, isbn_his, color_his, fecha_inicio_his, fecha_final_his, idusuarios_his, codlibros_his)
                                                    VALUES($tit, $aut, $edit, $isbn, $color, $fechaP, $fecha, {$_SESSION['idusuarios']}, $libro)";

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I tried find the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'del Web, Creative Commons, 123213, rojo,
>   2013-11-04, 2013-11-05, 127, 12)' at line 2

Please, can you help me? I couldn't find the error.

Comment: "$_SESSION['idusuarios']" contains WHAT?

Comment: i think your session contains an array.

Comment: and it's `${SESSION['idusuarios']}`, the `$` begin in front of the `{`, not inside.

Comment: this part contains the id of users, sorry for my language, idusuarios = idusers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your query with quotes:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO historial(`titulo_his`, `autor_his`, `editorial_his`, `isbn_his`, `color_his`, `fecha_inicio_his`, `fecha_final_his`, `idusuarios_his`, `codlibros_his`)
                                                                VALUES('{$tit}', '{$aut}', '{$edit}', '{$isbn}', '{$color}', '{$fechaP}', '{$fecha}', '{$_SESSION['idusuarios']}', '{$libro}')";
```

The problem is that you are trying to insert strings without enclosing them into quotes, so the query will fail

PS: And don't use *mysql_** functions the extension is deprecated.

PS2: Backticks for field names are not required, but i like it :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, about the values inside of $query it works too!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use php variables inside the query.

```
<?php
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prestamos LEFT JOIN libros  on  prestamos.codlibros = libros.cod_libros where id_usuariospr ={$_SESSION['idusuarios']}");
            $row = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if(isset($_SESSION['idusuarios']))
    $sessionvar=$_SESSION['idusuarios'];


        while($datos = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

                $tit = $datos['titulo'];
                $aut = $datos['autor'];
                $edit = $datos['editorial'];
                $isbn = $datos['isbn'];
                $color = $datos['color'];                
                $fechaP = $datos['fecha_prest'];
                $fecha = $datos['fecha_entrega'];
                $libro = $datos['codlibros'];

                $query = "INSERT INTO historial(titulo_his, autor_his, editorial_his, isbn_his, color_his, fecha_inicio_his, fecha_final_his, idusuarios_his, codlibros_his)
                                                                VALUES($tit, $aut, $edit, $isbn, $color, $fechaP, $fecha, $sessionvar, $libro)";

                      mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
          }                 

            ?>
```

Also for character fields values enclose them within quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add curly braces near a php variable in the query.
Another thing if a value is a string type then use it as-- '.$phpvariable.'